# Which parts in the diagram are syncronizers?

Tags: nissan, manual-transmission

I have a 99 Nissan Almera ( similar to the Sentra ) with a GA16DE engine and RS5F31A manual transmission.  I quite likely have a bad fifth gear synchronizer, and am trying to find what part to order.

I found [this site](http://www.nissanpartsdeal.com/) which has allot of interactive Nissan OEM diagrams and found this breakout of the transmission internals:

[image]

[Here is an interactive version of the diagram](http://www.nissanpartsdeal.com/parts-list/1999-nissan-sentra-b14u/transmission-gear.html?Filter=(2=GA16DE)&PNC=32267) which pops up part names.

I'm wondering which parts are the synchronizers, and what name they're calling them by.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parts labelled RING-BAULK (32604 in your image) are the synchronizers. Do a search for Baulk Ring and you will find some descriptions.  For example - https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DoYaRsNFlEYC&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq=BAULK+ring&source=bl&ots=3PXYSDFriB&sig=WHMXOOAG06AIShqixrw1w1K1hro&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiszKbql-HNAhVH9mMKHX3cAf4Q6AEISjAK#v=onepage&q=BAULK%20ring&f=false

Comment: Spot on, Howie.

Comment: Just curious, are these baulk rings the same thing as a blocking ring?

Comment: That's probably not a good idea to wait for me, lol!

Comment: Yes, blocking, syncro, balk (never seen *baulk*, but Nissan is not my native language).  I never wait for Paulster2.... I prefer to provide him endless opportunities to correct me goodly and proper.